# find substrings in sql table using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column of "name" in my sql table.  In my sql query i want to fetch all the records where column "name" is substring of my input string.

For exapmle, user enters "My name is Davivd", then I want to fetch all the records where name is David. 
P.S: User may enters something like this "Its David here".

Anyone who knows please let me know. Thanku

Comment: I think OP doesn't want this, he's saying the user will enter `Its David here`. I don't think this is doable, unless you have solution to know which part of the string the user enters is actually his name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple view of this would be:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(255)
SET @x = 'My name is David'
SELECT a FROM tablex WHERE @x LIKE '%' + tablex.name + '%'
```

This reverses @shortspider's response.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you have a name column you can find it as part of any string using the `CHARINDEX` function:

Example:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), NAME VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE(NAME)
SELECT 'DAVID' UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLIATH' UNION ALL
SELECT 'DAVE' UNION ALL
SELECT 'MARTIN'

SELECT *
FROM @TABLE
WHERE CHARINDEX(NAME,'DID YOU EVER READ THE STORY ABOUT DAVID AND GOLIATH?') > 0

SELECT *
FROM @TABLE
WHERE CHARINDEX(NAME,'MY FAVOURITE MOVIE DIRECTOR IS MARTIN SCORCESE. I LOVE HIS GLASSES.') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%David%'`

Comment: User may enters any string, so we dont know where is the name in string, your query won't work.